# iOS: Saving core data multiple views

Tags: ios, core-data

I'm new to iOS development--I'm working on passing data between different views...

Let's say I have a list of ten questions. Each question will have a different page with a transition between and the UI will contain a prev/next button along with the input collected for each question.

How do I display each question and collect the data in "steps", then finally save everything as one entry in a Core Data model?

Could you step me through how this is done? Much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: I would use a singleton to store the data, and then call save on the singleton at the end of the interview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as inafziger mentioned it would be best to use a singleton, but not at the end of each view, on your last view call save data, as this would improve performance. It sounds as though the data is relevant to your entire application.

If that is the case i would put ur:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;
```

Inside of your application delegate, this way you can access them from anywhere and if you need to fetch information from a previous question you can perform that action with great ease.

i hope this helps

**Edit:**
 (in regards to your comment)

Assuming you have the same or similar layout for each question, you could push a new instance of the same `ViewController` with the a different param ie

```
UIViewController* myNewVC = [UIViewController alloc] init];
[myNewVC setQuestion:self.question+1];
[[AppDelegate sharedDelegate].navigationController pushViewController:myNewVC animated:YES]
```

Or something similar to the above, also note, UITableViewController is always a UIViewController but a UIViewController isn't always a UITableViewController.

This way you can display a new question each time and reuse the exact same `ViewController`
for each question

Comment: Yes, thank you. My more important thought is this: How do I slide-animate pages when the next button is clicked? I don't need a new view controller for each question...This is a new concept for me.

Comment: That is a new question entirely, but i will edit my question to answer  your comment

Answer (score 0):

I would store the questions in the data model with a question entity which has an attribute question number. Then I would have my view controller track current question number in an ivar. Each time you go forward or backward you either increment or decrement the current question number and fetch the question from the core data.

I strongly suggest to avoid coupling different pieces of your code to your app delegate. Instead Apple encourages you to pass the necessary data structures from view controller to view controller either by setting a property or using delegate pattern.